# How can I stop Immediate GUI from selecting all text on click

Tags: unity-game-engine

Unitys Immediate GUI insists on selecting all contents of any text-based input field (TextField, TextArea, IntField...) every time you click into it (and it hasn't got focus already).

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: This question and answer is like asking about how to boot up Windows 95 and then answering it. IMGUI should not be used unless for Editor plugins. You should be using Unity's new UI system (uGUI). Again, anything with `OnGUI` or `GUI.XXX` should not be used.

Comment: I am indeed working on Editor tools. IMGUI is the only GUI I have there, and I am facing the issue I described in the question.

Comment: In that case, it's fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unity itself does not offer a way to prevent this.

After trying many solutions I found elsewhere and failing I did some reverse engineering and came up with the following workaround.

This wrapper method will prevent select-all by temporarily setting `cursorColor.a` to 0. Internally, Unity will only do select-all when the cursor is not transparent.

```
private T WithoutSelectAll<T>(Func<T> guiCall)
{
    bool preventSelection = (Event.current.type == EventType.MouseDown);

    Color oldCursorColor = GUI.skin.settings.cursorColor;

    if (preventSelection)
        GUI.skin.settings.cursorColor = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0);

    T value = guiCall();

    if (preventSelection)
        GUI.skin.settings.cursorColor = oldCursorColor;

    return value;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
int foo;
string bar;

foo = WithoutSelectAll(() => GUI.IntField("foo", foo));
bar = WithoutSelectAll(() => EditorGUILayout.TextArea(bar));
```

Answer (score 0):

@Thomas Hilbert

change

```
bool preventSelection = (Event.current.type == EventType.MouseDown);
```

to

```
bool preventSelection = Event.current.type != EventType.Repaint;
```

Comment: In what way will this improve the solution? Try to not only describe what to do, but why to do it, too.

Comment: Mouse down is not the only event triggers selection. Sometime when you click on the gap between to lines, it still select all the text inside EditorGUI.TextArea.